# Good ping indicator?

Tags: internet

I have *the* worst Internet ever, it constantly fluctuates from a normal ping of around 40ms, to over 5000ms.

I'm a keen "Gamer" and this irritates me so much, I know there's not much to do other than get a new service provider, but is there some sort of un-intrusive ping indicator software I could use to keep a good monitor of it. I'm thinking of a little number in the task-bar-tray-thingy that would constantly show my ping in milliseconds.

Comment: I have been thinking of writing one that would actually log it over 24 hrs

Comment: that would be pretty cool

Comment: For longtime ping observation, have a look at https://www.pingplotter.com/. It has helped me in negotiating with an ISP.

Comment: There could be a lot of local issues that could cause such poor ping times. How sure are you that it's your ISP?

Comment: I have to reboot my router every time it happens, sometimes it'll work good for an hour or so, or as it did just now, it'll go back to unusable even after a fresh reboot of the router.

Comment: @Tobi, if that worked for you, please consider the tick  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have written one as indicated above.  Options are

> Ping_Log [Options] Address
>
> /Cnn  = Ping nn in a Cluster (default 1)
> /CAnn = Ping nn in a Cluster and Average (default 0)
> /Rnn  = Ping every nn seconds (default 5)
> /Fnn  = For nn hours (default 0)
> /Bnn  = Buffer Size in bytes (default 32)
> /S    = Silent Mode (default Verbose)
> /Oxx  = Output to File xx (default none)

Here is a link for it

https://pacificblue.software/file?name=ping_log

Please let me know if you have any problems.